# Laravel Livewire - Select input data is lost after selection

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, selectinput

I am having Item (id, code, name & price), Warehouse(id & name) and Stock (item_id, warehouse_id, stock) models where Stock model is having item_id and warehouse_id relationship keys. I am trying to fetch items from stock model using livewire mount method

```
public $items, $selected_id;

public function mount()
{
   $this->items = Stock::select('item_id', 'warehouse_id')->groupBy('item_id', 'warehouse_id')->get();
}
```

and I am using this items in livewire component's select input

```
<select wire:model='selected_id'>

   @foreach($items as $item)
       <option value='{{$item->item->id}}'>{{$item->item->code}} - {{$item->item->name}} </option>
   @endforech

</select>
```

This working perfectly fine on initial loading. but when I select a item from items select input, all items are lost and getting empty array in options.

I do not have idea on what is wrong in this code. Please help me to figure out the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Short answer

You should only use public accessible properties for those that should be modifiable by the front-end. Keep `$selected_id` as a property, but change the `$items` property to a variable that you pass to the view in the `render` method, or a computed property.

```php
public $selected_id;

public function getItemsProperty()
{
    return Stock::select('item_id', 'warehouse_id')->groupBy('item_id', 'warehouse_id')->get();
}

public function render()
{
    return view('some-view', [
        'items' => $this->items,
    ])
}
```

#### Explaination

*Disclaimer: I haven't verified this with the debugger, but this is my best guess.*

Livewire serializes public properties to formats it can send to the frontend. That's why you are limited to primitives (`string`, `int`, `array`, etc.) and some classes (`Model` and `Collection`). Livewire serializes `Collection` and `Model` under the hood to some format so that it can perform the query again in the next render, preventing stale `Models` in subsequent requests.

I think this doesn't work properly, because you're using a `groupBy` in your query for the `$items` property.